# RewriteRule for URL Subdirectory Root

Tags: htaccess, redirects

Have not found this in my searches on SE.

I need this scenario to work:

• User visits **someurl.com/news/folder** or **someurl.com/news/somefolder/**, they get redirected to **someurl.com/somefolder**.

• If the user visits JUST **someurl.com/news** or **/news/**, they are allowed through to visit **/news**.

Here is my current rule: **RewriteRule ^news/(.*) /$1 [NC,R=301,L]**

How do I make it allow the second bullet point? First seems to work with no issues.

Thanks all!

**POST UPDATE**

I have got the code

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^news 
RewriteRule ^/news news/ [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news/(.*)$ RewriteRule ^news/(.*) /$1 [NC,R=301,L]

BUT - it doesn't allow me to go to the URL something.com/news/

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `.*` in your rewrite rule use `.+`   The star means zero or more characters, the plus means there has to be at least one.

```
 RewriteRule ^news/(.+) /$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Then you don't have any problems with that rewrite rule interfering with /news or /news/